# Python re.search excluyendo texto

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy realizando una búsqueda en una string del siguiente fragmento:

```
SSL80509060
```

Con el siguiente código:

```
nSerie = re.search(r"SSL(\d+)",linea).group()
```

El output de esta búsqueda es:

```
SSL80509060
```

Debería obtener únicamente el numero `80509060` sin el parámetro de búsqueda, SSL en este caso, ¿hay manera de hacerlo con el código que estoy usando?

Comment: Revisa los parámetros de [re.Match.group](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html#re.Match.group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa `findall`, que devuelve una lista con todos los patrones capturados, del cual te interesa el primero:

```
nSerie = re.findall(r"SSL(\d+)",linea)[0]
```

Pareciera que `search` simplemente captura todo el grupo.